# Using @Parameter annotation or ITestContext to read TestNG configuration file?

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

I found out that there are 2 ways to read parameters in testng xml configuration file:

1. use `@Parameter` annotation and define parameter names after the annotation
2. use `ITestContext` as an argument for the test class, DataProvider or Factory and use `getCurrentXmlTest()` and `getParameter()` to read the parameter.

Is any of these ways preferred for any reason on the other one? and is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the difference is the scope.  If I would need the same parameter across all my suite of tests for eg. env variables, I would use it in a listener implementing ITestListener or ISuiteListener (for suite scope) and then use the ITestContext/Suitecontext to apply the value across all my tests under `<test>`  or under `<suite>`

However, if I need very specific params for specific testcases, then I would go with @Parameter annotation on those particular testcases.

Also, the @Parameter can only take simple values, so there may be usecases where your tests need different objects (rather than strings) based on some param value.  In which case I would prefer a dataprovider, reading the param value( your second option, though argument for testclass i think is incorrect), creating objects and then feeding it to the tests. (for eg. probably name of a properties file is a param value, which is read and objects created based on data in the properties file and fed as different testdata to tests).